Manipulate and InputField Behavior
I'm trying to understand InputField behavior when used with Manipulate.
Here a small example:
Manipulate[ rndNum = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {vals}]; Text[rndNum], {vals, 0}]

When a number is entered for vals(ie 7) and the Enter key is pressed, several random numbers are generated.

If I hit the Enter key again without changing vals, no new random numbers are generated.
If I erase vals value and enter same value again and hit Enter, nothing is generated.
If I change the value in vals InputField and hit Enter new random numbers are generated.
If I enter the original value 7, new numbers are generated.

I'm trying to understand case 1 and 2. My expectation would be to reevaluate rndNum even though the value of vals has not changed.
It seems a reevaluate event happens on Enter key press, but no change in vals is preventing anything further.
Is there some other setting for Manipulate to allow this action ?
Thanks for any help.

So when I evaluate exactly what you've provided, I get two manipulate items, which are incessantly and constantly  making new values. (version 14.0).
I can solve this and reproduce your observations in two ways. Using ToString inside the Text call works, and so does using := instead of = for rndNum. I do not have an explanation for why either of those change the behavior but they do.
As for the behavior you are describing, I do not think it does reevaluate upon hitting enter, but only when the value has actually changed

As Tapiocaweasel pointed out in the comment, the numbers are actually generated only when the value of vals is changed. When you press Enter, you set the value of vals, but if the value is the same, this will not trigger the reevalution of your expression (and hence regeneration of new numbers). If you are interested in more details about dynamic, I suggest Introduction to Dynamic.
Instead of relying on Manipulate, you can just create your own InputField. Then, assuming you do not want to have a separate button, but instead use the Enter key for regeneration of numbers, you can wrap your InputField in EventHandler to listen for the keyboard events. At each Enter key press, you regenerate random numbers:
DynamicModule[{vals = 0, rndNum = {}}, 
 Column[{
   EventHandler[InputField[Dynamic[vals]], 
    "ReturnKeyDown" :> (rndNum = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {vals}])], 
   Dynamic[rndNum]}]]



Thanks so much. I knew something had to process key down events and EventHandler is it.
